# Why does animation type not change? anime.js

Tags: javascript, object, animation, anime.js

I have this anime object:

```
anime({
                targets: animAttrId,
                translateY:{
                    value: [-500,0],
                    duration: 900,
                    easing: 'easeInOutSine'
                }
            });
```

no matter which animation I put into the easing key, it always just moves at constant speed... I also tried it without the translateY being an object and erasing value, but the animation didn't change either...?? What am I doing wrong?

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and changing the easing works fine. Is your variable `animAttrId` selecting the correct element? Here's my code sample html:

```
<div class="target-element"></div>

<style>
    .target-element {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        left: 0%;
        top: calc(50% - 100px);
        background-color: purple;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var animAttrId = document.querySelector('.target-element');
    anime({
        targets: animAttrId,
        translateY: {
            value: [-500, 0],
            duration: 900,
            easing: 'easeOutBack'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Most animations can be accomplished by CSS and do not require a JS libray. Here's a simple bounce animation.

```
    <div class="target-element"></div>

<style>
    .target-element {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        left: calc(50% - 100px);
        top: calc(50% - 100px);
        background-color: purple;
        animation: myAnimation .5s cubic-bezier(0.83, 1.69, 0.54, 0.8) forwards;
    }

    @keyframes myAnimation {
        0% {
            transform: translateY(0%);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translateY(100%);
        }
    }
</style>
```

You can play around with the cubic-bezier curve directly in the chrome dev tools:

[image: dev tools cubic bezier]

Comment: Thats weird! If I change the easing it doesn't change? But the object still moves.. it just moves at a constant speed. So the selecting does work fine

Comment: Maybe there's some other CSS oder JS that effects the animation. What happens if you set a different target element?

Comment: That is weird, cause if I just set no easing, the standard one with first going to fast and then pulling back always starts. What Im really searching for is an animation, that looks like it would bounce off the ground

Comment: You can probably create that animation with pure CSS. I've added an example to the answer.